# Optical Character Recognition from Access via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ocr

I wish to OCR a few JPEGs (I can convert on the fly with iview).

I get:

```
Method 'OCR' of object 'IImage' failed
```

My code isn't perfect yet as I am focused on getting the .ocr method to function.
The images are photos and contain only a few characters. I could use a barcode reader, but those are hard to find free.

```vb
Public Function OCRtest(strTempImg)
    pXname = "ocrTest"    
    On Error GoTo err_hand  
    
    Dim miDoc As Object
    Dim miWord As MODI.Word
    Dim strWordInfo As String
    
    Set miDoc = CreateObject("MODI.Document")
    miDoc.Create strTempImg
    
    ' Perform OCR.
    miDoc.Images(0).ocr
    
    ' Retrieve and display word information.
    Set miWord = miDoc.Images(0).Layout.Words(2)
    strWordInfo = _
      "Id: " & miWord.id & vbCrLf & _
      "Line Id: " & miWord.LineId & vbCrLf & _
      "Region Id: " & miWord.RegionId & vbCrLf & _
      "Font Id: " & miWord.FontId & vbCrLf & _
      "Recognition confidence: " & _
      miWord.RecognitionConfidence & vbCrLf & _
      "Text: " & miWord.Text
        
    Set miWord = Nothing
    Set miDoc = Nothing
      
    OCRtest = strWordInfo
    Return
    Exit Function
    err_hand:
    Call CStatus(Error, 504, Err.Number, Err.description, strTempImg)
    
End Function
```

Comment: What version of MS Office have you installed?

Answer (score 1):

If you use MS Office 2010, you need  [install MODI](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982760/install-modi-for-use-with-microsoft-office-2010) firstly.
Then, you need to add reference to: `Microsoft Office Document Imaging 1x.0 Type Library` and you'll be able to use this code:

```
Sub OCRReader()
Dim doc1 As MODI.Document
Dim inputFile As String
Dim strRecText As String
Dim imageCounter As Integer
inputFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
strRecText = ""
Set doc1 = New MODI.Document
doc1.Create (inputFile)
doc1.OCR ' this will ocr all pages of a multi-page tiff file
For imageCounter = 0 To (doc1.Images.Count - 1) ' work your way through each page of results
    strRecText = strRecText & doc1.Images(imageCounter).Layout.Text ' this puts the ocr results into a string
Next
fnum = FreeFile()
Open "C:\Test\testmodi.txt" For Output As fnum
    Print #fnum, strRecText
Close #fnum
doc1.Close
End Sub
```

Above code comes from: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/358499-read-data-tiff-file-using-modi-ocr-vba.html

Comment: Sorry, this crashes access. I broke it, found it crashed where you'd guess, at the .OCR method. That thing is cursed. I forgot to mention another code I found did this. I wanted to thank you for a speedy reply.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm not so familiar with MODI, so i can't help you more.

Comment: I hope you could share the fix for the crash, as it happens to everyone it seems, no one has solution only same problem :S